# use ssh-agent to connect to vagrant-lxc machines

Tags: ssh, vagrant, lxc

I'd like to connect to a vagrant-lxc machine using a ssh-key which is already loaded. To make it a little bit more clear, here's my setup:

1. Load ssh-key in Windows via PuTTy
2. connect to vagrant host machine via Putty with agent forwarding enabled

After the second step I'd like to bring up the vagrant-lxc machine and ssh into it with the key which was already loaded before. Unfortunately I don't know how to configure vagrant to use this key. It is always using the default key ~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key or a specified keyfile from the Vagrantfile.

Is it possible to make vagrant use a loaded key from ssh-agent?

Regards,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your setup looks like this:

`Windows box with PuTTY Pageant + your private key -(PuTTY)-> Vagrant host machine -("vagrant ssh")-> LXC box`.

In any case, you should let the sshd running on LXC box know about your public keys: put the public key as a separate entry to `$HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys`, where `$HOME` is the home directory of the user you log in with (`"vagrant"` is default, but use whatever you chose before). Note that this is the public part of the key that you load into PuTTY's Pageant. Note also that PuTTY private key format is *not* compatible with OpenSSH, so you can't use your PuTTY's private key file with ssh on your Vagrant host box.

This will probably be enough.

I cannot test the setup identical to yours, but `"Windows box -(Putty)-> some host (ssh)-> some other host"` combo works with the configuration I mentioned. I assume that `"vagrant up"`, which you most likely use, does nothing fancier than calling whatever `ssh` you have on Vagrant host with the `"vagrant@<lcx-box-ip> -P <vagrant-ssh-port>"`, meaning that SSH does the actual key exchange. In this case everything works as I described.

If this does not work for some reason, try `"vagrant ssh -p"`, or try connecting from your Windows box via PuTTY directly to the LXC box -- Vagrant has forwarded the SSH port 22 of LXC box to some other port (2222 is default), so connecting via PuTTY to `"vagrant@<vagrant-host-ip> -P 2222"` should work as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately vagrant doesn't just use the binary ssh-client of the system. It uses a ruby library called net-ssh. My skills in ruby are less than basic, so I can't fix it myself ;)